# How to Call A .NET Created DLL in VB6 Application?

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I need to call a VB.NET DLL in VB6 application, does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

[How to call a Visual Basic .NET or Visual Basic 2005 assembly from Visual Basic 6.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20120210204121/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817248)

[Using .NET DLL in VB6](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1194639/Using-NET-DLL-in-VB)

Comment: Link is dead. VB6 should be dead as well but here we go, fun fun fun...

Comment: You're right, shouldn't have downvoted for that. But revenge downvoting... that's a whole new level man xD

Comment: 23 hours had passed unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You can also export functions as standard windows DLL function entry points if you're willing to use a post compile tool

Check out

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/DllExport.aspx

Works a treat and lets you integrate with all sorts of apps using Native VB.net when it'd require C or asm otherwise.